# Breaking out of one JS function to call another JS function

Tags: javascript, function, goto

Let's say that I have a series of functions:

```
function a(){
   //do this, do that
   b();
}
function b(){
   //do this, do that
   c();
}
function c(){
   //do this, do that
   // program ends at this point
}
a();
```

You would assume that from executing the code, we go from `a()` to `b()` to `c()` and the program terminates...

What I'm wondering is... is it possible to place code somewhere within the `// do this, do that` part of `b()` that depending on certain conditions to return to `a()` and then proceed through without the need of returning where it left off in `b()`, although if needed could then launch `b()` afresh?

I know, what you're thinking... "This is a JavaScript `GOTO` question, surely!" and to a degree it is... but seriously, is it possible to break from a function A completely and go to function B without having to worry about it returning to function A to finish where it left off?

Comment: `depending on certain conditions to return to a()` You answered your own question: `return "value";` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's `return` statement like this

```
function a(){
   //do this, do that
   b();
}
function b(){
   if (some_random_condition) {
      return;
   }
   c();
}
a();
```

The `return` statement makes it possible to go to `a` without having to execute the rest of `b` function.

Comment: I tried the following:

`var a, b;`
`function fa(){a = 1;b = 10;fb();}`
`function fb(){document.write("a = "+ a + "<br>");fc();}`
`function fc(){if(a<b){a++;fb();return;}else{document.write("That's the end.<br>");}}`
`fa();` and amazingly it worked how I had hoped...
Thanks!